# python combining values column wise for a batch of csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have a batch of more than 100 CSV files of format:

```
time,0
user time,0.6
CPU load, 5%
swaps,0
etc
```

I have to merge all of these files -
This code gives me the desired output
join -1 1 -2 1 -t, -a 1  f1.csv f2.csv  >res.csv

```
time,0,0
user time,0.6,0.8
CPU load, 5%,7%
swaps,0,0
etc
```

But I can give only 2 files as parameters
Is there a way to write a python code to iterate on all csv files in a directory (even a bash file would work)

Comment: Yes, you can do that, both in Python and Bash. That said, if you have problems with that, please describe precisely what problems you have. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Lastly, please read the description of tags before blindly applying them. More specifically, the "linux" tag was simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? It uses `glob` to open all .csv files in the current working directory (except for output.csv, if it exists):

```
def main():

    from pathlib import Path
    from contextlib import ExitStack
    from csv import reader
    from collections import defaultdict

    master_dict = defaultdict(list)

    glob_pattern = "[!output]*.csv"

    with ExitStack() as stack:
        readers = [reader(stack.enter_context(path.open("r"))) for path in Path(".").glob(glob_pattern)]
        for reader in readers:
            for row in reader:
                key, value = row
                master_dict[key].append(value)

    with Path("output.csv").open("w") as master_file:
        for key, value_list in master_dict.items():
            master_file.write(",".join([key] + value_list) + "\n")

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```